# A custom jquery posts slideshow?

Tags: themes

I would like to hvae something like which is under LATEST ARTICLES:

http://themeforest.net/item/equilibrium-clean-and-modern-wp-portfolio-theme/full_screen_preview/505517

I can quite easily build it with jquery slide effect, but I have no idea how to make it update automatically everytime I submit a new post. So, does anybody know how could I build this feature for my blog or maybe there is a plugin for this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic lists of posts in WordPress are based on concept of [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). You will need to retrieve sets of posts (with [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or in other way), you want displayed, and iterate through it to generate markup for slider to use.

There are many slider plugins for WordPress around you can look up and study.